# How do I read more than one byte with BufferedInputStream

Tags: java

This is an exact quote from my text:

```
The purpose of I/O buffering is to improve system performance. 
Rather than reading a byte at a time, a large number of bytes are read together 
the first time the read() method is invoked.
```

However, when I use BufferedInputStream.read() all I can do is get a single byte. What am I doing wrong and what do I need to do?

Comment: Technically, you don't need to do anything -- most calls to `read()` will deplete the internal buffer instead of making a system call every time, so the buffering is taken care of for you. You can also check out the [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/BufferedInputStream.html#read-byte:A-int-int-) for a more useful method.

Comment: How do I access the data in the buffer then? Where is the reference to the buffer?

Comment: You don't directly -- it's abstracted away from you. You access the buffer the same way you use a "normal" `InputStream`. The reference in the buffer is hidden away inside the `BufferedInputStream` class.

Comment: Then how would I do anything with it? Such as output it somewhere?

Comment: The point is that *you don't need to do anything special*. You can think of it as simply enhancing the performance of a regular `InputStream`. No need to treat it differently. There shouldn't be a reason to access the buffer directly.

Comment: As per the java docs 
protected volatile byte[] buf
The internal buffer array where the data is stored. When necessary, it may be replaced by another array of a different size.

Comment: So you could always extend this class if you really need to access the internal buffer - not sure why you would want to though

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not you, it is the stream that reads more than one character at a time. The `BufferedInputStream` keeps a buffer, and next time you call `read()` the next byte from that buffer is returned without any access to a physical drive (unless the buffer is empty and the next chunk of data has to be read into the buffer).

Note there are methods that read more than a byte, but these don't really have to do with the difference you explicitly asked for in your question.

Answer (score 0):

The BufferedInputStream class facilitates buffering to your input streams. Rather than read one byte at a time from the network or disk, you read a larger block at a time.

You can set the buffer size to be used internally by the BufferedInputStream with the following constructor

```
InputStream input = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream("PathOfFile"), 2 * 1024);
```

This example sets the buffer size to 2 KB

When the BufferedInputStream is created, an internal buffer array is created. As bytes from the stream are read or skipped, the internal buffer is refilled as necessary from the contained input stream, many bytes at a time